# How to keep a detective looking for the reason for a suicide

Tags: plot

Something I'm working on in my mind- a detective is called in to investigate what turns out to be a man having taken his own life. Once it's confirmed to be a suicide, it stands to reason the detective's superiors would want him to close the case and move on, but if that happens I have no story. So how do I explain the detective continuing to probe the suicide and find the motive for it?

Answer (score 0):

How culturally acceptable is suicide?  His bosses may want him to discover that it was an accident to cover up his family's shame that he killed himself.

Answer (score 0):

<⚠️> *(Content warning: discussion of suicide methods and suicidal thinking, as far as would be applicable to a criminal investigation. Do not read answer if sensitive.)*

### Something's not right with the case, the crime scene, or the autopsy report.

**One or two small details about the case are off, and your detective can't get it out of his head.** Detectives tend to develop a knack for when something's not quite "right" about a case, and something small about this case makes that sense go off the charts.

- Maybe the case file states that the man had sworn off alcohol and never drank, but there was a half-empty bottle of vodka in the basement fridge, and the fingerprints on it match the victim's.
- Maybe he was a vegan and a diehard health nut on the Atkins diet, but there were detectable levels of beta-blocking medication in his system.
- Maybe he recently settled a long-held dispute with a relative who he had written out of his will, and wrote them back into his will the week before he died - making it an awfully convenient time for him to die.

Whatever it is, something's just not right here, and the detective feels the need to press further. It's just bothering him, like an itch in his brain. Maybe the explanation is innocuous, but maybe it's something else...

Alternatively...

### The crime scene is *too* perfect.

The opposite of the scenario above, maybe the crime scene is just so completely textbook that this itself is suspicious. **It's *too* clean of a crime scene - almost as if it was staged, or he had help.**

If it was a hanging, for example, perhaps the knot is perfectly tied and the chair is perfectly arranged just so, in a manner that suggests he didn't at all struggle or kick the chair haphazardly during his exit - almost as if it was placed under him by someone else. Alternatively, maybe a relative comments that he was completely useless at knot-tying, so the detail of the knot being flawless sticks out in the detective's mind - how could he have made such a clean knot, especially while emotionally distressed as a suicidal person would likely be?

Whatever the case may be, something just seems a little... too convenient about the whole thing, and your detective gets suspicious of it.

### He didn't seem suicidal, emotionally unstable, or depressed, and has no history of mental illness.

As @Murphy L suggests, maybe this man is known to be very emotionally stable, wealthy, happily married, or otherwise generally has a happy life. There were no instigating negative events in his life that could have prompted him to take the final step - he didn't recently lose his job, and may even have recently been promoted; he doesn't have any marital problems, and wasn't in any danger of losing custody of his children. Moreover, he may have no history of diagnosed depression, bipolar disorder, or any other major mental illnesses.

**The detective is then left to wonder why such a happy man would suddenly take his own life.** If there is no motive, and no other obvious answer, then why would he do it?

It is of course true in the real world that sometimes there simply is no answer to the question of "why," and that it is a sad, horrible question that the living are left to ask. In the real world, people often face their demons quietly and privately, and there is nothing anyone could have done to help them if they could not help themselves. But this is crime fiction, and usually there is expected to be some kind of understandable answer to the question of "why," even if that's not always true in reality. And that, in the end, is what your detective will ask. *Why?*

Answer (score 0):

### Tropes

suggests 2 very common Mystery tropes:

**Suspicious suicide** – often a murder disguised to look like a suicide, or a red herring intended to throw the detective off their investigation (which might be an actual suicide but a false confession note to protect or frame someone else)

**Underdog detective** – when a police detective defies superiors to pursue their own investigation, which functions exactly like the trope where an uncooperative private detective is told by the police to stay out of it. It makes the main character (ostensibly with authority and a gun) appear to be an outsider/underdog.

There are *so many* examples of these specific tropes in mystery genre – each has [**well-known subversions that have become sub-tropes**](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/NeverSuicide) – readers will expect a 'payoff' that will refer back to the mystery plot, if not a full twist with the opposite revealed.

### match the Theme and Tone

Your in-story reasons can't be random. **Major character motivations are directly connected to your theme.**

- Is he honest but his superiors corrupt? We will see signs of corruption, vice, and grift throughout the story.
- Is he having a mental breakdown and unable to remain objective? We will see other
  cracks through his work and failing relationships.
- Is he a dog-with-a-bone
  bloodhound who can't let go of a nagging clue? The suicide is a puzzle to solve.

The other major factor will be tone. Whatever your readers are suppose to feel about this, will be signaled by his emotional state. Are readers meant to be alarmed, sad, intrigued?

### Avoid cliché

In real life [suicides are more common than murders](https://www.cdc.gov/nchs/pressroom/sosmap/suicide-mortality/suicide.htm), and he would know that just from being on the job.

If you want a psychological character-study of someone with a hero-complex that is cracking apart, any 'trigger' could keep him fixated on that one particular suicide. The real trauma is something else, something he hasn't connected yet.

If you want a cozy mystery idea, I just saw a plot where the suicide was discovered to be murder because the poisoned eyewash had been replaced label-backwards in the medicine cabinet. Clues out of context are inane, but I like the ones where putting the clues on a timeline of events reveals some inconsistency in the 'known' events.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe they knew each other, and it seems heavily out of character. Say, he/she has never seemed depressed and always was cheerful. (Or maybe, taking the idea further, he doesn't want to accept that it was a suicide. He/she continues to attempt to find the true killer, and whether or not they succeed is up to you.)

Answer (score -1):

The detective will have his own reasons to continue researching about the suicide; the two main obvious branches one can think of, top of the bat, are:

1. He DOES believe his friend did commit suicide, but it was so out of character that he needs more in-depth info about how it happened... His motivation in this case is restlessness, trying to find some closure...
2. He DOES NOT believe his friend committed suicide, despite all the evidence... His motivation in this case is, like any good detective, getting to the heart of the matter, and also getting the murderers to avenge his friend.

Depending on which path you take, you're going to be telling a different story; perhaps 1) is more about development of a character (learning the circumstances that took him to take his life, maybe the detective discovers that he could have done something to avoid it...), while 2) would be more a whodunit/conspiracy kind of plot, maybe. Then there is a somewhat "hybrid" possibility: he did take his own life, but it was under coercion -a drug or hypnotic device that forced him-, so it was suicide but not really, it was murder by his own hand...